# timeout when querying a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I am able to connect to and use various databases on my SQL Server at 192.168.5.180.

When I use the query editor of my application, then I successfully add the server by:

```
sp_addlinkedserver(sp_addlinkedserver '192.168.5.180').


select * from [192.168.5.180].CRM_QA_V3_SYNC_V1..CR_FAQ
```

When I try to execute a query from my database query editor I get the below error.

> Error:
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "192.168.5.180" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "192.168.5.180" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".

Both servers are SQL Server 2008.

Comment: So your saying that `select * from [192.168.5.180].CRM_QA_V3_SYNC_V1..CR_FAQ` times out?